# Not able to restrict my admin panel through .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I want to restrict access to my magento admin pannel from specific ip only. I have put the following code in the .htaccess file as suggested in few forums. However, whenever insert the following code my whole site is showing forbidden access. Following is the code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(index.php/)?admin/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^My_IP
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [R=302,L]
```

and

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from My IP
```

Kindly help!

Answer (score 1):

Remove this block:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from My IP
```

It forbids anyone from accessing your site unless they are using your IP. I'm assuming you replaced `My IP` with your IP address; if not, it will block you, too.

Comment: i have removed this block and restarted the apache server. now my site is accessible but even the admin panel is publicly accessible. have i inserted wrong code for rewrite cond. Please note that i have also installed mod_security. Does it conflicts with the .htaccess

Comment: @suhel how are you testing this?

Comment: I am accessing my server through jumpbox server. I have allready whitelisted the Jumpbox Ip in Modsecuirty. I could now access the my website from jumpbox server just fine. However, I inserted above code to restrict access to admin panel from public but the whole site got blocked.

Comment: @suhel Can you post the actual RewriteCond that has the IP? Feel free to change the digits, but it's impossible to know what might be wrong if we can't see your syntax. It should be something like `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.67\.89$`

Answer (score 0):

Your IP will change over time, so after about 24 hours your Internet Provider will have updated your IP address and you will no longer have access to your Magento admin panel.

*This is not a good idea.*